# How can I use this show password function for a different element on same page?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a show password function for a field on a page and want to use that same function on another field on the same page.  I added the reference elements via class and I don’t know how to make them both work independently, can someone advise please?

html

```
    <div class="password-field">
  <input id="password-input" type="password">
  <label for="password-input">Password input</label>
  <button type="button" class="show-password active">Show/Hide
    <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
  </button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="input-container">
    <input id="pin-code" type="password" maxlength="1" class="pin-input">
    <label for="pin-code">Password input</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <input id="pin-code" type="password" maxlength="1" class="pin-input">
    <label for="pin-code">Password input</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <input id="pin-code" type="password" maxlength="1" class="pin-input">
    <label for="pin-code">Password input</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <input id="pin-code" type="password" maxlength="1" class="pin-input">
    <label for="pin-code">Password input</label>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="show-password">Show/Hide
    <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
    $('.show-password').mousedown(function(event) {
  this.togglePass = $(this).siblings('input') //how to make this work as wel??
  this.togglePass = $(".input-container").find('input'); // this one only working
  this.toggleIcon = $(this).find('i');

  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $(this).attr('value', 'Hide');
  this.togglePass.attr('type', 'text');
  if(this.toggleIcon.length) {
    this.toggleIcon.toggleClass('icon-show-password');
  }
  else {
    $(this).text("Hide");
  }
}).mouseup(function(event) {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  this.togglePass.attr('type', 'password');
  $(this).attr('value', 'Show');

  if(this.toggleIcon.length) {
    this.toggleIcon.toggleClass('icon-show-password');
  }
  else {
    $(this).text("Show");
  }
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zincy/48az4j2o/2/

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You what I have done is I added a data attribute to your buttons so they are assigned a container since your container don't share the same class name, my solution was a bit more tricky since this can be done in multiple ways.

I also changed your variable names but you can change them back.

For the fault in your code, here is the explanation.
When I read through your code I saw that the mousedown/mouseup only focused on `.input-container` and not `.password-field` where your other input is located in, and the mousedown/mouseup function only focused on one `.show-password` where as in your code you had two of them, so with the previous fault in your code whichever button you clicked it would only trigger the function in the `.input-container`.

Solution is that I added a `.each()` for the `.show-password` and like I explained before I added a attribute to the button to store which container it should focus on.

```
<div class="password-field">
  <input id="password-input" type="password">
  <label for="password-input">Password input</label>
  <button type="button" class="show-password active" data-container=".password-field">Show/Hide
    <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
  </button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="input-container">
    <input id="pin-code" type="password" maxlength="1" class="pin-input">
    <label for="pin-code">Password input</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <input id="pin-code" type="password" maxlength="1" class="pin-input">
    <label for="pin-code">Password input</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <input id="pin-code" type="password" maxlength="1" class="pin-input">
    <label for="pin-code">Password input</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <input id="pin-code" type="password" maxlength="1" class="pin-input">
    <label for="pin-code">Password input</label>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="show-password" data-container=".input-container">Show/Hide
    <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".pin-input").keyup(function () {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');

  if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
    var $next = $(this).parent().next('.input-container').find('.pin-input');

    if ($next.length) {
      $next.focus();
    }
    else {
      $(this).blur();
    }
  }
});

$('button.show-password').each(function(){
  var selected_container = $(this).data("container"); // Get button container value
  var selected_input = $(selected_container).find("input"); // Selected input withing container
  var selected_icon = $(this).find('i');

  $(this).mousedown(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).attr('value', 'Hide');
    selected_input.attr('type', 'text');

    if(selected_icon.length > 0) {
      selected_icon.toggleClass('icon-show-password');
    }
    else {
      $(this).text("Hide");
    }
  }).mouseup(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).attr('value', 'Show');
    selected_input.attr('type', 'password');

    if(selected_icon.length > 0) {
     selected_icon.toggleClass('icon-show-password');
    }
    else {
     $(this).text("Show");
    }
  });
});
```

For jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/48az4j2o/4/